# What should I do with plugin-created migrations?

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have, as usual the `<project>/<app>/migrations` folder that I added to the version control for deployment. Since recently I am also using django-auditlog, which creates its own migrations in `<project>/env/Lib/site-packages/auditlog/migrations`. These migrations are applied just like my own ones. So I wonder: should I also add them to VCS and deploy them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You shouldn't deploy these migrations. In general you shouldn't deploy any third-party migrations.

The reason is simple. Third-party packages have their initial migrations inside their `migrations` directory. Each time you create a migration that depends on a third-party package, this migration will live in your app's `migrations` dir (not inside the package one).

So, when you first deploy your code and run `pip install -r requirements.txt` on your server, then all 3rd party packages will be installed and when you do `./manage.py migrate` then Django will look at your `INSTALLED_APPS` and execute all migrations for each one in this list.

The same thing happens with any third-party package, just like Django itself. Suppose you have in your `requirements.txt` file only `Django==1.10.6`. When you deploy this to the server and do `pip install -r requirements.txt`, `django-admin createproject myproject` and then `./manage.py migrate`, then your database will be "filled" with all Django-specific tables that has built-in (i.e `auth`, `sessions`, `contenttypes` etc) and are enabled in the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting list.

The one and only that you should deploy is everything under your project directory (`requirements.txt`, `manage.py`, `robots.txt` etc) and not your 3rd party apps which may live either inside your project (under a `.virtualenv` dir, probably) or in a separate `.virtualenv` dir outside of your project.

An analogous to your question is `node_modules` for nodejs. `node_modules` directory is never deployed to VCS (because it can get quite large in size etc), instead only the `package.json` is, because knowing what dependencies (`package.json`/`requirements.txt`) your project needs, then your project can "reconstruct" itself from zero.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It seems to make sense to me, but can you add one clarification please: Why is this different for my own migrations? Presumably we don't trust Django can always correctly rebuild them on deployment, so they should be version controlled. Why do we then trust Django's ability for the 3rd party app's migrations?

Comment: You may (or not) version control your apps' migrations but not 3rd party ones. Because, 3rd party apps lives inside your virtual env (under `site-packages` dir). You don't version control this dir. Upon deploy your project, you run `pip install -r requirements.txt` (note that each app under this file, has a version number) and all 3rd party packages are installed (along with any potential migrations they have). So, you're sure that each 3rd party will apply the correct migrations in your project. Does this clarify for you?

Comment: No :) It makes sense procedure-wise, it's also how I do it currently. But I am missing why I can trust the correct migrations will be generated and applied when installing 3rd party apps, but not when deploying my own one. If I understand correctly, the idea of deploying my own migrations via VCS is that migrations are not guaranteed to be created the way I want with `manage.py makemigrations`, so I want to be able to test them in advance. I can imagine e.g. admin site's migration generation is very well defined and reliable. Does the same apply to 3rd party apps? The discrepancy here bugs me.

Comment: Yes! Exactly that. The same applies for 3rd party apps, too. If one of your apps uses a 3rd party app (which needs to have its own db tables), then as long as you use the same version of that app and works locally, it'll absolutely work on production. I say *same version* because there might be a change in the future for that package (just a Django package changes things through it's version history), that may be backwards incompatible (major semantic version change).